# Prove these numbers are composite: $500^{27}-123^{12}$, $12^{75}+21^{75}$, $58^{32}-49^{32}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> I have to prove the next 3 numbers are composite numbers
>
> 1. $500^{27}-123^{12}$
> 2. $12^{75}+21^{75}$
> 3. $58^{32}-49^{32}$

I have no idea where to begin, if anyone can give me a hint I will be grateful.

Thank You Very Much!

Comment: Well, the usual way to start would be to look for small prime factors.  Or to search for "plynomial" factorings, as in $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). It doesn't have to be what you have tried: for example, where does this question come from?

Comment: This is a test of your algebraic skills in disguise. Your question is equivalent to showing that $a^{27} - b^{12}$, $m^{75} + n^{75}$ and $p^{32} - q^{32}$ factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

1. Can you write this in the form $a^3-b^3$? Now recall the formula for the difference of two cubes.
2. $\gcd(12, 21)= 3$, so you can find a common factor.
3. Use the difference of two squares.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I see its easy!

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.

Comment: Will do, thank you.